# s3 codeigniter file upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file on s3 but i keep on getting this one error

**finfo_file(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/53524141_124875748624301_192447137957543936_o.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

The library i am using is the one i found on github called [s3-codeigniter](https://github.com/alyahmmed/CodeIgniter-S3-Upload)

```
   $dir_s = dirname($_FILES["syllabus"]["tmp_name"]);
   $destination_s = $dir_s . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES["syllabus"]["name"];
   $syllabus = $this->s3_upload->upload_file($destination_s);
   $dir_i = dirname($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
   $destination_i = $dir_s . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
   $image = $this->s3_upload->upload_file($destination_i);
```

I think it is an issue with the path of  file but I am not sure

Comment: the $dir_s is assumed to be folder on S3 bucket ?

Comment: Could you provide the error info you are getting ?

Comment: Message: finfo_file(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/53524141_124875748624301_192447137957543936_o.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: libraries/S3_upload.php

Comment: your library file is not loaded yet. you are missing something in configuration of the library

Comment: Hey can you answer the steps or give me a small demo

Comment: Have you followed the steps writter here https://github.com/alyahmmed/CodeIgniter-S3-Upload ?

Comment: Already did followed all the steps

Comment: Can you check either your file uploaded in temp folder or not?

Comment: you need to include the library $this->load->library('s3_upload');

Comment: already included in my code

Comment: @RajdipChauhan the file is not present in the temp folder

Comment: where did you put all the files  from the github folder. can you please send me the path

Comment: give read write permission to your temp folder

Comment: @RohitJain: you need to give write permission(755) to your temp folder.